# Write EXIF-data from TIF (read with exifread) to JPEG-file using PIL (Pillow)

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library, exif

I'm writing a function that does some specialized image manipulation and saves the image in JPEG format. Naturally, the metadata should be preserved as much as possible. I'm using PIL (Pillow) and succeeded to do it with JPEG files as input data, since PIL is able to read the EXIF-data in this case.

However, for TIF images the info-dictionary does not contain an 'exif'-key. Using the module exifread, reading the exif data works fine, like so

```
import exifread
f = open('tifimage.tif')
img_exif = exifread.process_file(f)
f.close()
```

Now I'd like to pass this exif-data to PIL when saving, e.g.

```
img.save(filename, "JPEG", exif = img_exif)
```

But I cannot find out how to format the exif data properly, since they come in as dict type from exifread, but need to be in raw-string format or read-only-buffer for PIL.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: As far as I know, we need to find a way to build the EXIF binary byte string from a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we are looking for is probably Pyxif: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pyxif

The library is just doing that.

You can grab the current Exif information from:

```
im = Image.open(file_path)
exif_data = im.info['exif']
```

Then you can convert it in a dictionary with pyxif using:

```
zeroth_ifd, exif_ifd, gps_ifd = pyxif.load(file_path)
```

or

```
zeroth_ifd, exif_ifd, gps_ifd = pyxif.load(exif_data)
```

Then you can modify your `exif` dictionary and when you save your image, you can use:

```
zeroth_ifd[pyxif.ZerothIFD.Artist] = args.artist
zeroth_ifd[pyxif.ZerothIFD.Copyright] = args.copyright

exif_ifd[pyxif.ExifIFD.PixelXDimension] = size[0]
exif_ifd[pyxif.ExifIFD.PixelYDimension] = size[1]

exif_bytes = pyxif.dump(zeroth_ifd, exif_ifd, gps_ifd)

im.save(output_path, "JPEG", quality=85, exif=exif_bytes)
```

Comment: Thank you so very much, this works absolutely great! Ans without any dependenies, amazing... With my version of Pillow the EXIF writing process does not work, but pyxif.transplant() does the job.

Comment: The pyexif relies on exiftool.exe which puts itself as a wrapper utils. It seems not a clean solution. Is there any pure python tool to write EXIF? Why all solution is so clumsy?